Impact of Low Power Factor on Loss Generation in PMSMs
I am focusing on the losses generation in PMSMs and still have some doubts about the role of a low power factor.
For the analysis, I consider a three-phase PMSM controlled with Field Oriented Control (FOC), where \$I_{d}\$ is maintained equal to 0 to minimize resistive losses. Considering to impose a torque \$T\$, \$I_{q}\$ follows the relation: $$I_{q} = \frac{T}{k_{t}}$$
Resistive losses in the motor are equal to: $$P_{loss} = \frac{3}{2}R_s\sqrt{I_d^2+I_q^2} = \frac{3}{2}R_s\sqrt{I_q^2}$$
How does the power factor affect losses if \$I_{q}\$ is a fixed value imposed by \$T\$ and Joule loss depends only on \$I_{q}\$? Is it influencing other types of losses (es. iron losses)?
I know that \$P = V I cosϕ\$ and to get the same P with a low power factor I need to supply more current (or voltage), but from the previous equation I do not understand what am I missing.

What is the phase relationship between Id, Iq and V?

Sorry, I don't understand your question, can you rephrase it?
I calculate $I_q$, $I_d$, $V_q$ and $V_d$ from torque and speed and they are values, do not have a sinusoidal shape, so I do not have their phase information.
In a balanced system, I can calculate the active power $P$ and reactive power $Q$ using the following formulas from the provided link: $$P = \frac{3}{2} (V_d I_d + V_q I_q + 2 V_0 I_0)$$ and $$Q = \frac{3}{2} (V_q I_d - V_d I_q)$$
